# Repair tub liner with water trapped beneath

Tags: bathroom, leak, sealing, tub

The previous owners of my home installed a tub liner rather poorly.  The first time we used it, water was trapped between the liner an the tub.  The top portion is tile, the bottom is a tub with a liner.  How to get the water out without total destruction of the liner and replacing the tub? How can I seal the liner properly so more water does not get in?

Comment: IMHO, a sledgehammer is probably the right tool. Tub liners are a bad solution to a problem that has a good solution, called a new tub.

Comment: You may as well have suggested dynamite.  As I stated, I need information on how to get the water out, and seal properly so it does not get back in.  The liner is not something I normally would have chosen, but now I need to fix someone else's poor decision.  I'm looking for a repair solution, not a $5000 full bathroom remodel.  Try that sledgehammer option on your bathroom and let me know how it works out.

Comment: I did try it. I liked it. About $1200 later, the bathroom was good as new. Actually, better than new.

Comment: Regardless, your comments are not really relevant.  It would be nice if you answered how I can drain out the water and how I can prevent this from happening again.  I will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: While Ecnerwal's flippant attitude may be off putting, it really is the proper approach to your problem. IMO, it is not possible to achieve what you want. To remove the water and properly seal the liner would require complete removal and re-installation. If you're going to go through that much, you are truly much better off replacing the tub. Especially if you do not want the same thing to eventually happen again.

Comment: I think a picture would help.  This really depends how this tub liner is installed.  Also water should evaporate - adding a little heat helps.

Comment: Since water is trapped (i.e. it's not leaking to downstairs) then is it safe to assume the tub will hold water?  If that's the case, might it be possible to (temporarily) just remove the liner and use the tub as-is, making sure everything is sealed properly?